# calling xml to Android

Tags: android, xml, wcf, localhost, webhttpbinding

I have list of records in xml format from my local host "http:localhost:810/Service1.svc/leb/GetAllCustomers"

Can I call this to android and list it in Textview or Spinner or in EditTextView or in any of the controls in android?

Answer (score 1):

You should parse this xml file using SAX parse or Dom Parse in android and collect date in arrays/list/map according to your requirement here i am post some link to you get more information form there and get your ASAP.

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser

I hope this is very helpful to you.

Comment: thank u very much but i have xml format output but actually not an xml extension file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.

Use Intent which takes URL as an argument.

In the URL you can mention the location/URI of your source.

Then, you can parse it to a string and store it.

Later, use ArrayAdapter to populate.

I can get you code if this is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Some links here for you.

1) [Multithreading for Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

to help you understand, how to download a file (example shows downloading an image) via AsyncTask.

2) [Working with XML in Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html)

to help you parse your xml. Check these out. Good luck!